# Display VALUE parameter of DICOM image

Tags: c#, dicom, evil-dicom

I'm using the Evil Dicom dll. Currently for one of the tags, Counts Accumulated, I can extract and display the VR parameter, LENGTH parameter and TAG DESCRIPTION parameter.

However, I haven't found a way to extract and display the VALUE parameter, i.e. the physical number of the counts accumulated. Everything I have tried up to know keeps giving me errors.

Can someone be kind enough to give me an idea how to extract this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the EvilDicom [Getting Started page](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/getting-started), it should be as simple as this:

```
DICOMFile df = new DICOMFile("test.dcm");  
int[] countsDataArray = df.COUNTS_ACCUMULATED.Data;
int countsAccumulated = countsArray[0];
```

`COUNTS_ACCUMULATED` is of type [IntegerString](http://evildicom.rexcardan.com/API/html/class_evil_dicom_1_1_v_r_1_1_integer_string.html), which has a `Data` member that returns an integer array. The *Value Multiplicity* of *Counts Accumulated* is *1*, so you only need to access the first value in the `Data` array.